# undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass(path)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am beginner in Ruby who's looking to debug an issue in my "index" view. I am trying to list out different values for dataset. However, I am not sure where the issue lies in the following line of code.

```
 <% @datasets.each do |dataset| %>
   <%= Dir[File.join(dataset.ds.path[0,dataset.ds.path.to_s.length-4], '**', '*')].count
  <% end %>
```

Comment: Sounds like `dataset.ds.path` is somehow `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to appear when `dataset.ds.path.to_s.length-4` obtains a negative value, if that happens, you are accessing `dataset.ds.path[0,-4]` in case `dataset.ds.path.to_s.length` is evaluated to 0.

One way to work around this, if you're fine with negative indexes is to change `[0,dataset.ds.path.to_s.length-4]` into `[0..dataset.ds.path.to_s.length-4]`.

If not, then you could try defining a method in your `Dataset` model which return 0 if `dataset.ds.path.to_s.length-4` is less than 0 which would fix the problem for you since `some_array[0,0]` will return `[]`.